# Django ModelFormset: Using two separate models, one to render survey question, one to save responses

Tags: django

I am new to Django, and am stuck.  I am creating a survey using two models: one to describe the survey question, and one to store the response (either a choice of answers defined by QUESTION_ANSWER_CHOICES, or a text field):

```
class PassengerRequirement (models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    ...
    question_number = models.CharField(max_length=12, default=0, unique=False)
    is_yes_no_question = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Is this a Yes/No Question?')
    question_text = models.TextField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True, help_text="Put the question in this field.")
    ...

class PassengerRequirementMeasurement (models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    survey_question = models.ForeignKey('PassengerRequirement',
                                        related_name='passenger_requirement_answer',
                                        on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    survey_instance = models.ForeignKey('SurveyInstance',
                                        related_name='passenger_requirement_measurements',
                                        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                        null=True)

    answer_choice = models.CharField(max_length=1,
                                       choices=QUESTION_ANSWER_CHOICES,
                                       default=YES)

    answer_text = models.TextField(max_length=256,
                                   null=True,
                                   blank=True,
                                   help_text="Add Details")
```

Then using the modelformset_factory a formset in forms.py:

```
prFormSet = modelformset_factory(PassengerRequirementMeasurement,
                                 fields=('answer_choice', 'answer_text'),
                                 extra=0
                                 )
```

And my view:

```
def passenger_requirements_pretravel(request):

    surveyquestions = PassengerRequirement.objects.filter(...)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = prFormSet(queryset=PassengerRequirement.objects.filter(...),
                        data=request.POST)

        if formset.is_valid():
            print('no problem')
        else:
            print(formset.errors)

        ...

    else:
        formset = prFormSet(queryset=PassengerRequirement.objects.filter(...)
        return render(request, 'surveys/passenger_requirements_pretravel.html',
            {'formset': formset, 'surveyquestions': surveyquestions})
```

I am looping through the surveyquestions and formset to display the questions and form fields:

```
            <form action="{% url 'pr_pretravel' %}" method="post" class="mt-5">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ formset.management_form }}

                {% for question in surveyquestions %}
                    {% with cntr=forloop.counter0 %}
                    <div class="q_{{ question.question_number|length }} form-group">
                    <h5 class="font-weight-bold">{{ question.question_number }}:  {{ question.question_text }}</h5>
                        {% if question.is_yes_no_question == True %}
                            {% for form in formset %}
                                {% if cntr == forloop.counter0 %}
                                    {{ form.answer_choice }}
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% else %}
                            {% for form in formset %}
                                {% if cntr == forloop.counter0 %}
                                    {{ form.answer_text }}
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    {% endwith %}
                {% endfor %}

                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </form>
```

It's awkward I know but the only way I could figure out how to use both formset and surveyquestions.

The issue is, I can't get past the is_valid() method; it always returns a list of:

```
[{'id': ['This field is required.']}, {'answer_choice': ['This field is required.'],...
```

for each question in the list.

I've tried an approach modelled after [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623544/how-to-save-django-modelformset) but still get something similar:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>answer_choice<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

Any suggestions?  Thank you!

Comment: Can you add your template where you are rendering the formset

Comment: Added the template code.  It's awkward, but the only way I could get surveyquestions and formset to work together. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @IainShelvington would you have any ideas here?  I could use some direction.  Thank you.